# Use induction to prove that $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 $ is divisible by $9$

Tags: induction

Prove that for all integers $n\geq 0, n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 $ is divisible by 9.

1. If $ n=1, 1+8+27 = 36 = 9 * x $
2. Suppose $ n = k, k^3 + (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 $ is divisible by 9.
3. Find out $ n = k + 1, $ is divisible by 9.

Because $2$ is divisible by $9$. if $3$ is divisible by $9$, $3$ - $2$ will be divisible by $9$

and the result of $3$ - $2$ =  $ 9(k^2 + 3k + 3) $ which is divisible by $9$. So, it is proved.

What I found out the answer so far is them. Are they right way?

Comment: Don't you mean to replace $x$ with $4$ in 1? Edit: Also, the notation of using a number to represent an expression and doing arithmetic that way is terribly confusing.

Comment: $2$ is divisible by $9$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I believe he means the expression he lists as 2, that is $k^3 + (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The write up is rather confused; it is particularly bad to use "2" and "3-2" as you do, since it seems you are saying that the **number** $2$ is divisible by $9$, that $3-2$ (that is, that $1$) is divisible by $9$,  etc.

Spend the time writing out complete, coherent, self-contained sentences! Confused writing usually indicates confused thinking.

More specific comments:

1. Bad use of $x$ in your first step. Better to write out explicitly that $36$ is equal to $9\times 4$, hence divisible by $9$.
2. Write out *explicitly* what your assumption is: namely, your assumption is that there exists an integer $q$ such that
   $$ k^3 + (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 = 9q.$$
3. Write out *explicitly* what you need to prove. Namely, you need to prove that
   $$(k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 + (k+3)^3\text{ is divisible by }9.$$

Then you make a very bad mistake: you affirm the consequent. You are trying to *prove* that the expression in point 3 is divisible by $9$. You assume that it *is* divisible by 9, and then point out that if it is divisible by 9, then so is 
$$\Bigl( (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 + (k+3)^3\Bigr) - \Bigl( k^3 + (k+1)^2 + (k+2)^3\Bigr).$$

Then you note that this is indeed divisible by $9$, and conclude that the assumption must be true.

**This is a logical fallacy.** You are saying: "If $P$, then $Q$; since $Q$ is true, then $P$ must be true." If I fall into a pool, I'll get wet. I'm wet. Therefore, I fell into a pool. (Well, no, there are other reasons why I may be wet).

Don't assume what you are trying to prove. *Deduce it*.

Instead, what you want to do is to write out the expression you want, and try to use the fact that $k^3 + (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3$ is divisible by $9$ to conclude the expression you want is divisible by $3$. For instance, you can write:
$$\begin{align*}
(k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 + (k+3)^3 &= (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 + \Bigl( k^3 + 9k^2 + 27k + 81\Bigr)\\
&= k^3 + (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 + \Bigl( 9k^2 + 27k + 81\Bigr)
\end{align*}$$
and go from there to conclude that **if** $k^3 + (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3$ is divisible by $9$, **then** $(k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 + (k+3)^3$ is also divisible by $9$.

This completes the *Inductive Step*. Together with the *Base* (step 1), this establishes the desired result for all integers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ \  \bbox[1px,border:3px solid #c60]{\bbox[8px,border:1px solid #c00]{\forall\, n\ge 0\!:\ 9\ |\ f_n\!\iff\! [\,9\ |\ f_0\,\ {\rm  and}\  \rm\:\forall\, n\ge 0\!:\ 9\ |\ \color{#0a0}{f_{\,n+1}\!-f_n}\,]}}\ \ $ (typical [telescopy](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy))

because, $ $ if $\rm\ \ 9\ |\ \color{#0a0}{f_{n+1}\!-f_n}\ $ then $\rm\ 9\ |\ \color{#c00}{f_n} \Rightarrow\ 9\ |\ f_{n+1} =  \color{#0a0}{f_{n+1}\! - f_n} + \color{#c00}{f_n}\ \,$  (inductive step $\,\rm P_n\Rightarrow P_{n+1}$)

i.e. $\rm\: mod\ 9\!:\ if\ \ \color{#0a0}{f_{n+1}\equiv f_n}\ $ then $\rm\ \color{#c00}{f_n\equiv c}\ \,\Longrightarrow\,\ \color{#0a0}{f_{n+1}\equiv \color{#0a0}{f}_{\color{#c00} n}}\color{#c00}{\equiv c}\ $ so induction yields

that $\rm\:f\:$ is a constant function, so $\rm\ f_n\equiv f_0\equiv\: 0^3+1^3+2^3\equiv 9\equiv 0$.

This holds in OP by $\rm\ f_{n+1}-f_n = (n\!+\!3)^3\!-n^3 = 9\ (n^2\! +\! 3n\! +\! 3)\equiv 0\pmod{\!9}$.

This is a special case of *telescopic induction*. For further examples see [many prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy)